# Prove: if $f'(x)$ equals zero once, $f(x)$ equals zero twice

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, derivatives

Given $f(x)$ that is differentiable for every $ x \in R$,
if $f'(x) = 0$ only once, $f(x)=0$ only twice.

I'm having a bit trouble with this proof, I first said that

Let $c \in R$   such that $f'(c)=0$, f(x) is differentiable for every $ x \in R$, so according to Rolle's theorem we know that there exist $x_1\lt c \lt x_2$ such that $f(x_1)=0, f(x_2)=0$
But I don't know if that's sufficient or whether it is true at all.

Some help?

Thanks:)

Comment: "At most twice". Consider $f(x)=x^3$.

Comment: Is this the wording of the original question exactly?  There are certainly examples where $f'(x)=0$ exactly once and $f(x)=0$ never.  Therefore I would interpret this as if $f'$ has at most one root, $f$ has at most two roots.

Comment: For $f(x)=x^2+1$, $f'$ has one zero, but $f$ doesn't have any, so your "only" isn't correct.

Comment: That's not what Rolle's Theorem says.

Comment: Hint: Look at the "contrapositive", i.e., assume $f$ is differentiable and vanishes at three points. What can you deduce from Rolle's Theorem?

Comment: Argue like this: *if* $x<y$ and $f(x)=f(y)=0$, then by Rolle's Theorem, there is a $c$ with $x<c<y$ and $f'(c)=0$.  If $f$ had three distinct zeros, you could find two distinct zeroes of $f'$ (prove this).

Comment: what does $f(x)$ zero twice mean?

Comment: @DavidMitra, so $x^3$ is a contradiction for that?

Comment: Rolle's theorem says that for a differentiable $f$, if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)=0$ where $x_1\ne x_2$, then there is a $c$ strictly between $x_1$ and $x_2$ so that $f'(c)=0$. The converse is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false. Consider $f(x) = x^n$ where n is an integer